# **kwargs always giving none in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

Somewhere in my views i am redirecting as :

```
return redirect('camera_login', success='False' )
```

In my urls.py :

```
    url(r'^', CameraLoginView.as_view(), 
        name = "camera_login"),
    url(r'^(?P<success>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$', CameraLoginView.as_view(), 
        name = "camera_login"),
```

Now i can see the url is being redirected to `localhost:8000/False` in my browser, and the `camera_login.html` page is rendered, but when i debug the code, my `**kwargs` is always none.

```
class CameraLoginView(View):

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print('kwargs' , self.kwargs)
    success = None
    print('args ', args)
    return render( request,
        'camera_login.html', {'success': success})
```

in terminal `kwargs {}`, kwargs is always empty? I don't know where i am going wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first pattern matches everything, so your second pattern is never reached. Since the first pattern does not have a capturing group, no kwargs are ever captured.

You should make sure you always terminate your patterns:

```
url(r'^$', CameraLoginView.as_view(), name = "camera_login"),
url(r'^(?P<success>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$', ...)
```